# Feeding unknown length of list as input in a function

Tags: python

```
from itertools import product
vec=['A1','A2','A3']
vec2=['B1','B2',]
vec3=['C1','C2','C3']

result = list(product(vec, vec2, vec3,repeat=1))
result 
[('A1', 'B1', 'C1'),
 ('A1', 'B1', 'C2'),
 ('A1', 'B1', 'C3'),
 ('A1', 'B2', 'C1'),
 ('A1', 'B2', 'C2'),
 ('A1', 'B2', 'C3'),
 ('A2', 'B1', 'C1'),
 ('A2', 'B1', 'C2'),
 ('A2', 'B1', 'C3'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'C1'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'C2'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'C3'),
 ('A3', 'B1', 'C1'),
 ('A3', 'B1', 'C2'),
 ('A3', 'B1', 'C3'),
 ('A3', 'B2', 'C1'),
 ('A3', 'B2', 'C2'),
 ('A3', 'B2', 'C3')]
```

vec,vec2,vec3 are created from loop vec4 can be there sometimes with some length. My question is how do I feed vec4 in `list(product(vec, vec2, vec3,repeat=1))` . I can't enter it myself in a loop I want `product` to pick vec4 somehow also. How do I achieve this?
`vec4=['D1','D2','D3','D4']`

Comment: can you provide ```vec4```? You can put all the lists into a single list (say ```lists```) and then do ```itertools.product(*lists,repeat=1)```

Comment: @Sujay edited please check. If we put it in a single list cartesian product is different. Could you please loop it and tell me how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have all vec lists in a single list of lists using, you can unpack this list when passing it to the product function:

```
list_vecs = [vec, vec2, vec3, vec4]

list(product(*list_vecs, repeat=1))
```

Concerning the * (star-notation) see the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

> For instance, the built-in range() function expects separate start and stop arguments. If they are not available separately, write the function call with the *-operator to unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple:

```
>>> list(range(3, 6))            # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> list(range(*args))            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

In case `vec4` is only defined later, just append it to the `list_vecs`: `list_vecs.append(vec4)`

Comment: It did work but I want to what is the use of an asterisk here.

Comment: ```*``` is for unpacking the list @Damandeep

Comment: @Sujay Thanks if you can put a solution in any other way. That will be a learning for me.

Comment: @mcsoini Could you please see my two recent questions.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is almost the same as @mcsoini, but a little more explanation:
Here,

```
vec=[['A1','A2','A3'],
['B1','B2'],
['C1','C2','C3'],vec4]
```

`vec` is a list of lists. The first 3 lists are `vec1,2,3`. `vec4` can be added later on. Also, you can add more lists to `vec` using `vec.append(<list>)`

Now, instead of doing `vec[0],vec[1]...`, we will simply use then `*` for unpacking the list. This will pass all the lists in the `itertools.product()`.

```
list(product(*vec,repeat=1))
```

Also, this takes care of the nuber of lists because doing `vec[0]...` is not only tedious but also lead to errors if the index is out of range, or will only consider those lists which are indexed.

```
vec=[['A1','A2','A3'],
['B1','B2'],
['C1','C2','C3'],vec4]

result = list(product(*vec,repeat=1))
```